# 1 and 0 not recognized as boolean constants in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

If I try to run this query in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT ( 0 )
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An
>   expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ')'.

Sometimes when debugging complex WHERE statements I will cut out pieces and test a particular scenario by inserting something like `1=1` for true.  I would prefer to just use `1` or `TRUE` but this doesn't work in the above case.  Why is it not able to evaluate `NOT( 0 )` as a boolean expression?

Edit: This does work fine, showing that I don't have to add a column:

`SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(1<>1)`

Comment: `Select 1` works in SQL Server. There is no need for `where` condition.

Comment: @LukLed That has nothing to do with the error.  The error is referring to the where condition.  I used `SELECT 1` for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0 and 1 are integers. They are not themselves boolean expressions and in SQL only expressions can have a value of TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN. Saying "NOT 7.5" for example is not itself a boolean expression. In actuality, what you are trying to say "NOT (7.5 <> 0)" Thus, in your example, you would need to convert your value to an expression:

```
Select 1 Where Not ( 0 <> 0 )
```

In T-SQL at least, there are no constants that you can use for TRUE and FALSE. I.e., there is no means to query for :

```
Select 1 Where Not TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, you understood my question.  So I guess there are is no boolean constant that can replace "0<>0" ?

Comment: I've never had a need for this but have seen people use "WHERE 1=1" and "WHERE 1=0". These give you good boolean conditions without double and triple negatives.

Comment: @aaronls. In T-SQL at least, no. There are no constants for TRUE and FALSE. You simply have to accept that any boolean expression can end in TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 1):

0 and 1 are not boolean constants, they're [bit constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

because the WHERE clause is separate from the SELECT clause

you can select completely different things in the SELECT that are not even in in the WHERE clause

for example

```
select name, address, state, company, country
from bla
where occupation='programmer'
and hobby ='debugging'
```

so where not (0)  would mean what in this case, you need to add the column

```
AND RegionID <> 0
```

or

```
AND RegionID NOT IN (0) --althoug if you have NULLS in coumn this won't work
```

Comment: I reallize I can select different things from the where.  I am not concerned with the select side.  I am talking about the boolean expression on the WHERE side that is generating the error.  It's a boolean expression without a column.  Why do I have to add a column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT ( 0 )
```

In the where clasue you have to have a comparison, where what = what, where what <> what etc. You can't have a comparision with only one value. It needs to know what you are trying to compare the 0 to.